MySQL max_prepared_stmt_count Issue on Shared Hosting (Hostinger)
MySQL max_prepared_stmt_count Woes on Shared Hosting (Hostinger)
Hey devs,
The senireo is different from the other topics available on the Stackoverflow & none of the solutions worked given there.
And I am not asking for the prevention as I am aware of it, just need help with solving this.
So here’s the deal—I’m running MySQL on Hostinger’s shared hosting plan. I’ve got some PHP files talking to my database. In one of them, I straight-up forgot to call stmt->close() after using a prepared statement. Yeah, rookie mistake, I know. Now I’ve completely blown through the max_prepared_stmt_count limit, and MySQL is not having it.
The exact Error messsage:
uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 100000) in <filepath>
The Setup

Environment: Hostinger shared hosting (read: no config file or terminal access).
Problem: Hit the max_prepared_stmt_count ceiling because I didn’t clean up my prepared statements.
Obvious Solutions:

Crank up max_prepared_stmt_count.
Restart MySQL.



The Brick Wall
But guess what? Shared hosting life means:

I can’t touch MySQL configs.
No terminal access to restart anything.

My Burning Questions

Is there any clever hack to reset the prepared statement count without a server restart?
Any Hostinger-specific sorcery I might be missing?
How can I bulletproof my code going forward—other than the obvious “don’t forget stmt->close()” advice?

What I Tried
Here’s the play-by-play of what I’ve already done to tackle this:

Googled like a madman: Dug through every link I could find, but everything points to solutions involving server restarts or MySQL config tweaks—both off-limits in shared hosting.
Pinged Hostinger support: Hit them up, and (surprise, surprise) they confirmed there’s no way to tweak server-level settings on shared hosting.
Hacked around in hPanel: Scoured every corner of the hPanel for some hidden gem of an option, but came up empty-handed.

TL;DR:
I’m stuck. If anyone has some ninja-level workaround or insights, I’m all ears.

you need to kill all processes manually

You don't need to kill anything. Just close your prepared statements when you're done with them. No config changes needed, no restarts, no killing. This is totally solvable in your code.

How is forgetting to call stmt->close() a rookie mistake? Why would you even need to call it? Most of the time, you don't need it, so what exactly was the "rookie" mistake that required you to use it.

I am very confused about your issue. How small is the limit on prepared statements that you are running into it? What does it mean that you are stuck now? Why would this setting even matter? Even if we consider a shared hosting and the default 16k prepared statements, you'd need 16k simultaneous prepared statements. Is that really what you have now?

I have only one solution: do not open more than 100k prepared statements at once. If it's from 100k simultaneous requests then obviously you need a dedicated hosting.

@Dharman, It would be inevitable to have 16k prepared statements or 1 million prepared statements in any long-lived process, if any case of creating a prepared statement fails to close it. In traditional PHP code, this would never happen because of the shared-nothing property. Resources are automatically close when the request ends. But not all apps are written like that. Some loop indefinitely, allocating new prepared statements. In that case, one needs to take care to close them.

And don't use stmt->close(). If you have to use this function then it means you have something very wrong in your code design.

@BillKarwin I am pretty sure you would run out of available PHP memory before then. It's a lot to keep open at the same time.

And yet there are many questions posted to SO from people who get errors about max_prepared_stmt_count...

"Is there any clever hack to reset the prepared statement count without a server restart?" Yes, restart PHP process if it's a CLI process.
